# Rotate the placement of 4 images

Tags: javascript, image, rotation

So now that i have figured out how to swap two images I have discovered that I have to do it again but now with 4 images, rotating each of them left whenever the button is clicked. I tried using the same code that was used for the two images but it instead turns every picture to earthrise.jpg. Here is my code

```
function rotateLeft() {
    var image1 = document.getElementById("image1")
    var image2 = document.getElementById("image2")
    var image3 = document.getElementById("image3")
    var image4 = document.getElementById("image4")
    if (image1.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg')>-1) {
        image1.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg';
    }
    if (image1.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg')>-1) {
        image1.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg';
    }
    if (image1.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg')>-1) {
        image1.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg';
    }
    if (image1.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg')>-1) {
        image1.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg';
    }            
    if (image2.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg')>-1) {
        image2.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg';
    }
    if (image2.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg')>-1) {
        image2.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg';
    }
    if (image2.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg')>-1) {
        image2.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg';
    }
   if (image2.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg')>-1) {
        image2.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg';
    }      
    if (image3.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg')>-1) {
        image3.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg';
    }
     if (image3.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg')>-1) {
        image3.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg';
    }
    if (image3.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg')>-1) {
        image3.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg';
    }
    if (image3.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg')>-1) {
        image3.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg';
    }    
    if (image4.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg')>-1) {
        image4.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg';
    }
    if (image4.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/earth.jpg')>-1) {
        image4.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg';
    }
    if (image4.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/maine.jpg')>-1) {
        image4.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg';
    }
    if (image4.src.indexOf('/jmurphy9/111/images/baywindows.jpg')>-1) {
        image4.src = '/jmurphy9/111/images/earthrise.jpg';
    }      
}

function init(){
    var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
    button1.onclick = rotateLeft;
    }

window.onload = init;
```

Like i said, when the button is clicked it changes every picture to earthrise.jpg and I'm not sure why.

Comment: The pictures will all end up as earthrise.jpg because you're setting each image to that picture explicitly in the last conditional of every image*x* var.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swapping the position of two images with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909512/swapping-the-position-of-two-images-with-javascript)

Comment: Why did you ask the same question ~1 hour apart?

Answer (score 0):

If your 4 images can be contained in a span or a div, rotate left by appending the first image to the parent container. It will move to the last position, and the other images will slide over or up, if they are not absolutely positioned in their parent. Doesn't matter what the id or the source is-

btn.onclick= rotateLeft;

if they are the only content in their container:

```
function rotateLeft(pa){
    var pa= pa || document.getElementById('shiftingImageContainer');
    pa.appendChild(pa.firstChild);
}
```

or if they are separated by other content on the page:

```
function rotateLeft(pa){
    var pa= pa || document.getElementById('shiftingImageContainer');
    pa.appendChild(pa.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
}
```